# Как удалить четные индексы элементов из массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

подскажите как можно удалить четные индексы элементов из массива ?

```
        for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        a[i] = a[i * 2 + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        cout << "[" << a[i] << "]";
```

написан был такой код ,но он же не удаляет.

Для решения моего потребовалось изменить цикл ,и уменьшать размер массива

```
        for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        a[i] = a[i * 2 + 1];
        n--;
    }
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под удалением? Освободить память?

Comment: @vp_arth , полное удаление что бы при цикле for(i = 0; i<n; i++) эти числа(четные индексы ) не выводились

Comment: Не уменьшая при этом n?

Comment: @vp_arth,ой кажется начал понимать свою ошибку,размер же должен уменьшаться .

Comment: Все же - четные элементы (как в заголовке) или элементы с четными индексами (как в тексте)? Должен ли соблюдаться относительный порядок остающихся элементов?

Comment: @Harry, Элементы с четными индексами.

Comment: Если Вы создали массив для 10 элементов, то он всегда будет хранить в себе 10 элементов.

Comment: Да, я сколько я понимаю эти значения заполняются 0 вместо удаления ,верно ?

Comment: Сами они ничем не заполняются, можете заполнять их чем угодно.

Comment: Понял ,спасибо.

Comment: "Удалить" ничего нельзя. Можно перезаписать. Можно выделить память и освободить (в куче, но не на стеке, там это происходит автоматически).

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете просто сдвинуть все нечётные в начало. И записать, что размер массива теперь другой. Но это абстракция. В общем-то так это и делается. В том же векторе есть size и capacity.

Comment: @Egorithm,у меня есть задание удалить максимальный элемент в массиве ,я знаю какой именно это элемент индекс и значение ,как мне сделать чтобы при выводе всех элементов не вывело этот элемент ?

Comment: @Egorithm,разобрался .просто сдвинул и уменьшил размер массива .Верное решение ?